# How to preserve offset of a child div relative to its container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to implement a map using jQuery and Bootstrap 2.3.

So there is a Map image wrapped with a Container div named container along with another draggable div as a location picker:

```
    <div class="row-fluid margin-bottom-10">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="span6 center">
                <div id="mapContainer" class="relative">
                    @this.Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Location.MapPositionLeft)
                    @this.Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Location.MapPositionTop)
                    <img id="mapImage" src="~/Content/Images/Visitors/map.png" />
                    <div id="mapPicker" class="draggable mapPicker absolute"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my js:
        initiateMapPicker: function () {

```
        var mapPicker = $("#mapPicker");
        var mapContainer = $("#mapContainer");

        if (mapContainer.length == 0)
            return;

        var top = eval($('input[type="hidden"][name="Location.MapPositionTop"]').val());
        var left = eval($('input[type="hidden"][name="Location.MapPositionLeft"]').val());

        if (!top && !left) {
            top = 0;
            left = 0;
        }

        mapPicker.draggable({
            containment: "parent",
            stop: function () {
                // Get new position
                var position = $(this).position();
                $('input[type="hidden"][name="Location.MapPositionLeft"]').val(position.left);
                $('input[type="hidden"][name="Location.MapPositionTop"]').val(position.top);
            }
        // assign saved position
        }).offset({ top: mapContainer.offset().top + top, left: mapContainer.offset().left + left });
    },
```

well, it works!
BUT: on window resize, everything breaks down.

How can I position the picker relative to container and preserve the location of picker according to the image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for draggable(), you need to specify a container selector, not just "parent".. so something like:

```
mapPicker.draggable({ containment: "#mapContainer", ... })
```

Also, make sure that your #mapContainer has a CSS position other than static (relative or absolute), to make sure any CSS offset for children applies in an expected way, relative #mapContainer and not some other div or body.

Hope this helps!